# How to show error as username exists or email exists using php while registration

Tags: php, mysql, registration

Hi friends am trying to show errors as username already exists or email exists while registering using php. Here is my code..

```
   if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $unique_user = "SELECT * FROM `user` where username='$username' or email='$email'";
    $unique_result = mysqli_query($mysql, $unique_user);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($unique_result)>0)
       {
           echo "try again";
       }
```

Right now am printing try again but how can I check whether it is username or email already exists

Comment: Am storing username,email,password in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to only show **Username Or email exists** instead of username exists and email exists.
Anyway here is the code:

```
       if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $unique_user = "SELECT * FROM `user` where username='$username' or email='$email'";
        $unique_result = mysqli_query($mysql, $unique_user);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($unique_result)>0)
        {
          while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($unique_result))
          {
              if($res['username']  == $username)
              {
              echo "Username Exists";
              }
              if($res['email']  == $email)
              {
              echo "Email Exists";
              }
          }
          echo "Please try again";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$unique_user = "SELECT * FROM `user` where username='$username' or email='$email'";
$unique_result = mysqli_query($mysql, $unique_user);                
if(mysqli_num_rows($unique_result)>0) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($unique_result)) {
              if ($row['username'] === $username) {
                 echo 'Username Exist!';
              } else {
                 echo 'Email Exist!';
              }
       }
}
```